# Stuck while deploying an artifact

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deploying

I tried to deploy the artifact, but when it touch:

```
04-Jan-2019 15:42:04.909 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Aditya\Desktop\Brian\apache-tomee-plume-8.0.0-M1\webapps\manager] has finished in [494] ms
```

I waited for it more than just minutes, any solution?

Comment: Do you mean that several minutes had passed before that message appeared?

Comment: No, whent that message appeared, it stuck in there, there is no movement of all, no error, but its not running at all.